# How to show the little hand in a link that doesn't have the href attribute?

Tags: html, ajax, hyperlink

i have this link `<a>jander</a>`.

When I put the mouse cursor over it, the selection cursor is shown instead of the little hand.

Is there any way to show the little hand?

Note: I don't want to use href='#' because it is that case when I click on the link (it's a link that executes ajax function), it goes to the top of the page.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Style the cursor as so:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;">jander</a>
```

Comment: And if you are using Bootstrap you can use `<a role="button">text</a>`

Answer (score 5):

You can also do:

```
<a href="javascript:;">jander</a>
```

This prevents the scroll to the top of the page and keeps your links having an href attribute (ideal in some situations where CSS is locked or if you have a limiting CMS).

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
cursor: pointer;
```

in the element's style or class.  Note that this will work on any element — not just `a`.

By the way, you can always `return false` in your handler to avoid the problem you have with `href="#"`.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to set for all `<a>` attribute set this in your css file.

```
a {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `style="cursor:pointer;"` to your `a` tag.

Answer (score 1):

When you use links for JavaScript you can also use
`<a href="javascript:false">jander</a>` 
or 
`<a href="#" onClick="ajaxFunction(); return false;">` 
the return false will 'deactivate' the href attribute

Answer (score 1):

When using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), you can do the following:

```
<a role="button">jander</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

avoid inline styles! use a class

```
<style>
.no-href-but-gimme-pointer{cursor:pointer;}
</style>
<a class='no-href-but-gimme-pointer'>hover me for pointer, but don't click me -- i won't do anything!</a>
```